# PANDAS tricky groupby using multiple groups in a list within a single column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

Stumped. Imagine a dataframe with a column that contains multiple product category "tags", some of which are in a list, like so.

```
import pandas as pd

raw = {
    'Products' : ['Rock On Leather Journal',
                  'Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer',
                  'Garmin 25mm Wristwatch'
                 ],
    'Product Cost': [55,163,200],
    'Product Category' : [['Music','Journals','Paper'], 
                          ['Headphones','Music', 'Clocks'], 
                          ['Watches','Clocks']]
}

data = pd.DataFrame(raw)
```

What's the best way to get a count of how many Products within each Category, and to average the costs for each category? For example,

Music: Count-?, Avg Price-?

Normally this would be a straightforward process using a map or a groupby. But the presence of lists in the category column adds a tricky twist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source DF:

```
In [21]: data
Out[21]:
              Product Category  Product Cost                    Products
0     [Music, Journals, Paper]            55     Rock On Leather Journal
1  [Headphones, Music, Clocks]           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
2            [Watches, Clocks]           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch
```

First lets transform (flatten) it into the following DF:

```
In [22]: lst_col = 'Product Category'
    ...:
    ...: x = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     col:np.repeat(data[col].values, data[lst_col].str.len())
    ...:     for col in data.columns.difference([lst_col])
    ...: }).assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(data[lst_col].values)})[data.columns.tolist()]
    ...:

In [23]: x
Out[23]:
  Product Category  Product Cost                    Products
0            Music            55     Rock On Leather Journal
1         Journals            55     Rock On Leather Journal
2            Paper            55     Rock On Leather Journal
3       Headphones           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
4            Music           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
5           Clocks           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
6          Watches           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch
7           Clocks           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch
```

Now we can easily `"count of how many Products within each Category, and to average the costs for each category"`:

```
In [25]: x.groupby('Product Category')['Product Cost'].agg(['size', 'mean']).reset_index()
Out[25]:
  Product Category  size   mean
0           Clocks     2  181.5
1       Headphones     1  163.0
2         Journals     1   55.0
3            Music     2  109.0
4            Paper     1   55.0
5          Watches     1  200.0
```

**Some explanations:**

number of list elements in each row:

```
In [7]: data[lst_col].str.len()
Out[7]:
0    3
1    3
2    2
Name: Product Category, dtype: int64
```

using this information we can replicate all non-list columns as follows:

```
In [3]: x = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     col:np.repeat(data[col].values, data[lst_col].str.len())
   ...:     for col in data.columns.difference([lst_col])
   ...: })

In [4]: x
Out[4]:
   Product Cost                    Products
0            55     Rock On Leather Journal
1            55     Rock On Leather Journal
2            55     Rock On Leather Journal
3           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
4           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
5           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
6           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch
7           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch
```

now we can add flattened `list column`:

```
In [8]: np.concatenate(data[lst_col].values)
Out[8]:
array(['Music', 'Journals', 'Paper', 'Headphones', 'Music', 'Clocks', 'Watches', 'Clocks'],
      dtype='<U10')

In [5]: x.assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(data[lst_col].values)})
Out[5]:
   Product Cost                    Products Product Category
0            55     Rock On Leather Journal            Music
1            55     Rock On Leather Journal         Journals
2            55     Rock On Leather Journal            Paper
3           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer       Headphones
4           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer            Music
5           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer           Clocks
6           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch          Watches
7           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch           Clocks
```

and finally we simply select columns in the original order:

```
In [6]: x.assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(data[lst_col].values)})[data.columns.tolist()]
Out[6]:
  Product Category  Product Cost                    Products
0            Music            55     Rock On Leather Journal
1         Journals            55     Rock On Leather Journal
2            Paper            55     Rock On Leather Journal
3       Headphones           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
4            Music           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
5           Clocks           163  Beats Earbuds In Ear Timer
6          Watches           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch
7           Clocks           200      Garmin 25mm Wristwatch
```

Comment: this works! Although, I am still trying to understand exactly what's happening from the "for" col section all the way through your .assign(). It looks like what's happening is for each category, you're copying the row data into a new row so that each row has 1 category. Then, with the .assign() you're appending all of the other columns. But maybe I'm wrong. This is more complex than anything I've ever seen (albeit fantastic) and I hope you'll explain a bit further for anyone else who sees this post.

Comment: @Adestin, i've added some explanations - please check

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your case. If it's this size, you might want to create a boolean column for each element - e.g.

```
unique_products = set(chain(*data['Product Category']))
for product in unique_products:
    data['product_{}.format(product) = data.Products.apply(lambda x: product in x)
```

Alternately, if you've got a large pool of products, go ahead and use `data.Product.apply(lamba x: product in x)` as necessary.  You can also use [`data.Product.isin([product_one, product_two])`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to perform a a similar check.

Once you have a synthetic column, you can use that for merging.